# Получить значение из родительского потока

Tags: c#

Есть поток родительский который main программы и создан дочерний. 
В родительском есть меняющееся переменная. Дочерний должен время от времени получать значение этой переменной. Каким образом?

```
while (true) {
  // вот тут надо получить значение родительской переменной int pParam
  // и записать в дочернюю переменную int cParam
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Эм.. По ссылке на неё.

Answer (score 2):

Операции с int - атомарны. Так что просто присваиваем в родительском потоке, читаем в дочернем. И никаких проблем.

Comment: Верно, работает. А если допустим у меня много потоков. и я их создаю запускаю через цикл и так сказать забываю, с родительского потока обращений не будет на дочерние. А они в свою очередь будут выполнять какой либо код и так же им нужно получить значение этой переменной. Можно ли как то сделать чтоб на каждый потом из родительского не отправлять запись th[i].param = 0; а чтоб дочерние обращались и записывали к себе?

Comment: Если переменная объявлена в базовом классе, то она одна на все потоки. То есть сколько бы их не работало любая операция записи, или чтения будет автоматом доступна из всех остальных потоков). В принципе из всех).

Comment: У меня получается родительский поток запускает дочерний поток с другим классом. Тогда переменная из Form1 не доступна в thClass

Comment: Ну самый простой вариант (правда не самый красивый с точки зрения архитектуры): сделать статичный класс, в нем сделать статичную переменную... И писать/читать её из разных потоков. Более красивый (но более сложный), прокинуть родительский класс в конструктор базовых, и подключаться к переменным через прокинутую ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо большое за все ответы, Т.к. я новичек, решил все перенести в один класс. Благо в шарпе возможно разбивать один класс на несколько файлов через partial, именно так и сделал. Ибо в одном листинге тяжело читать, когда много кода.

Answer (score 2):

Для случая «общения» потоков в GUI-программе обычно используется встроенное в GUI-фреймворк средства выполнения кода в UI-потоке. Для WinForms это метод `Control.Invoke`, который нужно вызывать в фоновом потоке, а он выполняет переданный ему делегат в UI-потоке. При этом вы должны обращаться к контролам только из UI-потока, то есть, изнутри аргумента `Control.Invoke`. Явная синхронизация при этом не нужна, т. к. вызов `Invoke` сам является синхронизирующим.

Пример считывания значения поля класса или свойства контрола из фонового потока:

```
void Run() // фоновый поток
{
    // ... что-то делаем
    int cParam;
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { cParam = pParam; })
    // пользуемся ...
}
```

Этот код для случая, когда метод, который бежит в потоке, является методом самой формы. Если нет, нужно сответственно `form.Invoke` и `form.pParam`.

---

Для коммуникации между фоновыми потоками, или в случае не-GUI-программы всё сложнее.

Если у вас есть разделяемые между потоками данные, вам **необходимо** при чтении и записи из использовать `lock`.

Размер данных и «атомарность» не имеет значения, ведь оптимизатор вправе считать, что данные не меняются, если он не видит `lock` и запись в данном потоке (и тогда он имеет право закешировать переменную в регистре, например).

Если вам нужен поллинг значения из другого потока, это обычно организуется так:

```
class C
{
    int v;
    object vlock = new object();

    // для чтения
    void access()
    {
        bool iszero;
        lock (vlock)
            iszero = (v == 0);
        if (iszero) ...
    }

    // для записи
    void increment()
    {
        lock (vlock)
            v++;
    }
}
```

Не пытайтесь «сэкономить», пытаясь избежать синхронизации через `lock`. В подавляющем большинстве случаев в вашей программе есть на несколько порядков более расходный код, рядом с которым одни несчастный `lock` просто пылинка. Например, если ваша программа читает файлы или загружает данные из сети. Впрочем, обязательно спрофилируйте, говорить об оптимизации без профилирования абсурд.

Есть ещё немного более «дешёвые» примитивы синхронизации (`volatile`, memory barrier и тому подобное), которые могут помочь при определённых условиях, если вы хорошо понимаете тонкости модели памяти. Без хороших знаний по теме я бы не рекомендовал пытаться ими воспользоваться.

К сожалению, спецификация языка рассказывает о `lock` и его «соседях» в достаточно малопонятных терминах, поэтому приходится доверять мнению разработчиков языка.

Процитирую [статью Эрика Липперта](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/), одного из ключевых разработчиков языка C# (перевод мой):

> Если честно, **я вообще не рекомендую вам пользоваться volatile-полями**. Volatile-поле означает, что вы делаете что-то совершенно безумное: вы пытаетесь модифицировать и считывать поле в различных потоках без `lock`'а. Конструкция `lock` даёт гарантию, что память, прочитанная или изменённая внутри неё будет консистентной, `lock` гарантирует, что только один поток будет иметь доступ к данному участку памяти в данный момент времени и так далее. Количество случаев, когда `lock` слишком медленный, исчезающе мало, и вероятность того, что ваш код будет неправильным, потому что вы не понимаете подробности модели памяти, весьма велика. Я не пытаюсь избегать `lock`'ов никогда, кроме самых тривиальных случаев использования `Interlocked`-операций. Оставьте `volatile` для настоящих экспертов.

(Я лично считаю совет использовать `volatile` вредоносным.)

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме:

- [We need to lock a .NET Int32 when reading it in a multithreaded code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395306/276994)
- [Volatile keyword in C# – memory model explained](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/)
- [Atomicity, volatility and immutability are different, part three](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/)

Comment: Поправь меня верно ли я понял. Приведу пример. Работает форма с richtextBox который является логом потоков и (к примеру) 10 дочерних потоков созданных с потока формы. Время от времени нужно вернуть из дочерних информацию в лог (т.е. в richtextbox). На прямую обращаться нельзя (запрещено правилами c#, т.к. объект создан в другом потоке), обращаюсь через Invoke(action) что не есть хорошо т.к. возможно словить одновременное обращение дочерних потоков получив ошибку.

Comment: Попробовал сделать lock() { внутри Invoke}, зависает с концами (позже допер что lock локает не только дочерние, но и главный поток) и вместе нельзя использовать. Еще раз перечитал твой ответ и остановился на твоем примере поллинга. Получается мне нужно создать класс, и передавать с дочерних потоков в класс данные, а с главного считывать из класса. Т.е. кратко использовать класс как прокладку данных между главной формой и дочерними потоками.

Comment: Как то слишком муторно получается (ибо имею не только лог данных, но и еще куча всякой информации, которую придется чекать и перезаписывать в прокладку с разных сторон). Нельзя ли как то по другому сделать с обращением напрямую из дочернего в главную форму так чтоб останавливались другие дочерние потоки и не локалась главная форма? Или все же придется использовать поллинг, или изобретать свой lock?

Comment: @ИнокентийВас: Смотрите. Если вы перебрасываете данные в один поток через Invoke, синхронизация тоже не нужна, т. к. все операции с RTB происходят в одном и том же UI-потоке. При этом не стоит бояться, что будут «одновременно» работать два вызова: поток в каждый момент времени выполняет ровно одну функцию, и не прерывает её выполнение. Другие Invoke'и будут дожидаться окончания работы текущего.

Comment: @VladD странно советовать lock в том случае, когда нужен volatile. Хотя бы потому, что отключение кэширования в случае lock - хитрый сайдэффект, про который надо знать. В такой код, в котором чтение каждого int обернуто в lock, придет следующий разработчик, и со словами "int читается атомарно!" поудаляет локи.

Comment: @PashaPash: Наоборот. `lock` — это универсальное решение, которое работает **всегда**, а `volatile` может иногда работать, при выполнении сотни мелких условий, и ломается от любого чиха или косого взгляда в сторону кода.

Comment: @VladD например? они же через один механизим работают, и покрыты ровно одним куском спеки - тем самым  3.10 Execution order. никаких дополнительных условий нет.

Comment: @PashaPash: Механизм не важен, это implementation defined. А то, работает ли volatile, зависит от размера шины данных, от семантики  memory fence на данной платформе (full rw fence/acquire/...) и остальных мелких факторов. И это молча, без предупреждения от компилятора не сработает, если поменять `int` на что-нибудь другое.

Comment: @VladD так то же самое и для lock. у них же один и тот же механизим пробивания кэша. т.е. если не сработает volatile - то не сработает и lock (та его часть, что пробивает кэш).  "молча, без предупреждения от компилятора не сработает, если поменять int на что-нибудь другое" - компилятор ругнется, если вы поставите volatile на что-то, на чем он "не сработает"

Comment: @VladD ок, смотрите - вы вот можете указать на конкретное место в спеке, где сказано "lock запрещает кэширование"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60512/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladD  any low-lock code -> код без lock'ов? достаточно вольный перевод :)

Comment: @ИнокентийВас: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: И правда! Спасибо, подправил.

Answer (score 1):

Операции с int - атомарны, так что единственное, что может пойти не так - оптимизатор может закешировать значение вашей переменной, считая (по умолчанию), что работа с ней происходит из одного потока.

Для отключения "однопоточных" оптимизаций служит ключевое слово [`volatile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.120).aspx):

> Ключевое слово volatile указывает, что поле может быть изменено несколькими потоками, выполняющимися одновременно. Поля, объявленные как volatile, не проходят оптимизацию компилятором, которая предусматривает доступ посредством отдельного потока. Это гарантирует наличие наиболее актуального значения в поле в любое время.

Про наиболее актуальное значение в MSDN немного обманывают - по сути, установка `volatile` запретит рантайму переиспользовать значение поля, вычитанное при прошлом к нему обращении.

ECMA-335, I.12.6.7 Volatile reads and writes:

> An optimizing compiler that converts CIL to native code shall not remove any volatile operation,
>   nor shall it coalesce multiple volatile operations into a single operation.

---

Вместо использования `volatile` можно пооборачивать доступ к переменным в `lock`. Но стоит учитывать, что утверждение "`lock` косвенно отключает кэширование" закопано глубоко в дебри спецификации (спецификации CLI, а не C#), Срабатывает это отключение за счет того, что вход в `lock` сам по себе считается volatile read. Что запрещает оптимизатору выносить чтение памяти наверх из лока.

Т.е. если вы откроете справку по `lock`, то найдете только

> Ключевое слово lock не позволит ни одному потоку войти в важный раздел кода в тот момент, когда в нем находится другой поток.

Ни слова про кэширование. И следующий разработчик на проекте, знающий про `lock`, но не знающий про volatile, удалит ваши локи со словами "int32 читается атомарно, понаставили тут ненужных блокировок" :)

Comment: А вот таких горе-оптимизаторов, как ваш гипотетический «следующий разработчик», гнать взашей из проекта. Они вообще любую синхронизацию уберут, ведь «int атомарен».

Comment: Кстати, вы можете со ссылкой на документацию сформулировать **точный набор** гарантий, которые даёт `volatile`?

Comment: @VladD 10.5.3 + 3.10 есть точный набор гарантий. Применительно к этому вопросу - хватает гарантии "volatile read has “acquire semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction sequence.", которая, по сути не запрещает кэширование в регистре (его вообще нельзя запретить на 100%), но заставляет оптимизатор по крайней мере сгенерировать обращение к памяти и не отложить его "на потом". Т.е, теоретически, это запретит слить предыдущий volatile read этой же переменной с текущим volatile read - что, по сути, запрещает кэширование.

Comment: @VladD а вот lock сливать два вычитывания одной не-volatile переменной не запрещает вообще никак (если она не меняется в текущем потоке выполнения). то, что они не сливаются в текущей версии .net - это implementation defined

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, lock гарантирует as-if-правило: что переменная не будет закеширована _между_ `Monitor.{Enter,Exit}`.

Comment: «Для этого вопроса хватает гарантии» = очень хрупкое решение.

Comment: @VladD "хватит гарантии" - просто потому, что пол страницы текста в коммент не влезло. я скопировал то, что имеет отношение к конкретному случаю

Comment: @VladD какое конкретно место в спеке гарантирует что не-volatile переменная не будет закеширована до Monitor.Enter?, и что внутри лока не может быть использовано ранее закэшированное значение (мы же пытаемся решить проблему кэширования v до входа в lock)?

Comment: @VladD Давайте я обсуждение в чат снесу, а то слишком длинное получается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60514/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vladd).

Comment: Я покамест немного занят, но для затравки https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530556/276994

Comment: @VladD так с локами та же сама я проблема. т.е. для volatile справедливо "they do not actually guarantee that every processor stops what it is doing and updates caches to/from main memory". Достаточно очевидно, что volatile не отключает кэширование напрямую. Это не способ "пробить кэш". но точно так же - lock, это не способ пробить кэш. т.е. да, lock даст *совершенно ненужное в рамках этого вопроса* "every processor stops what it is doing", но никак не даст "updates caches to/from main memory"

Comment: @VladD давайте все-таки перейдем в [один из чатов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--), я там запостил длинное объяснение с примерами. Не надо бросать в меня ссылкой на стандартную статью, и тем более вольным ее переводом. Мы же пытаемся понять, что позволяет (якобы!) lock-у пробивать кэш (а volatile, в той же ситуации) - нет. И "leave the usage of “volatile” to real experts." - это плохой аргумент в данной ситуации.

Comment: @VladD нашел конкретное место в спеке, которое запрещает кэшировать в регистре результат прошлого чтения из памяти ("сливать чтения"), обновил ответ